# Reference equality test failed when trying to avoid consecutive same random number

Tags: java, javafx, random, equality

I am learning Javafx. I'm writing an quiz application for practice purpose.

Now I'm working on a feature about random question order. I use *javafx.scene.control.Button* to implement that, with *Random* class.

I'm trying to avoid consecutive random number, so I use an if-statement to test equality of two reference. 
The problem is that some times it doesn't work, I still got same consecutive random numbers and results which seems should not be there.

here is my code snippet:

```
buttonRandom.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        Question oldQuestion = currentQuestion;
        int randomIndexOfList;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (questionLibrary.getQuestionsList().size() > 1) {
                randomIndexOfList = randomGenerator.nextInt(questionLibrary.getQuestionsList().size());
                currentQuestion = questionLibrary.getQuestionsList().get(randomIndexOfList);
                if (currentQuestion == oldQuestion) {
                    buttonRandom.fire();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(currentQuestion.getIndex());
                    updateQuestionDisplay();
                }
            }
            else
                new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "There are less than 2 questions in Library.").showAndWait();
        }
    });
```

And here are some test results of it:

70
**93

93**
20
65
174
51
70
93
65
119
105
**47

47**
51

I also tried to test equality with *equals*() method(which is well implemented in *Question* class) or test *index* fields in *Question* directly, but problem stand still. And a test using a do-while loop had no help too...

I 'm using IntelliJ IDEA with java sdk 1.8 .0_181.

Most appreciated for any light  you can share, Thanks.

Comment: How do you define if two `Question` objects are equal?

Comment: Question object have a final instance integer field, index, which is unique. I use it to testing equality.

Comment: Did you override the equals method to compare the `index` field?

Comment: You say you are "trying to avoid consecutive random number" but it seems to me you are really trying to avoid repeating the same question. If that's the case, you don't need to avoid two 93s in a row; you need to avoid two 93s ever. The best solution to that is to _shuffle_ the questionList, randomize the order, then just iterate over the randomized list. `List<Question> questions = questionLibrary.getQuestionsList(); Collections.shuffle(questions);`

Comment: @GBlodgett, sure, properly overrided,

Comment: @StephenP, Thanks for your advice, which is definitely a quick way to solve my problem. But I still want to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Sure Chester, that's why I wrote a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Learn to implement a Bag class, it is trivially easy to do using a Java List.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. 
A very stupid mistake.
I mistakenly put the `Question oldQuestion = currentQuestion;` declaration out of `handle(ActionEvent event)` method, make `oldquestion` never be reassigned after the instantiation of `EventHandler`.

Correction:

```
        int randomIndexOfList;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Question oldQuestion = currentQuestion;
            if (questionLibrary.getQuestionsList().size() > 1) {
```

I should bang my head into some donkey arse.